# passing dynamic url into html/pug

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, pug

I have social buttons for sharing the current page on all my web application pages, the URL attribute is as follows `data-url="https://www.myPage.com/whateverComes"`. However, I am looking for a way to have this URL dynamically from the location.href. Is there a way to achieve this without having to use javascript? maybe just plain HTML or inline javascript.

I am using pug as templating engine, -window.location.href or #{window.location.href} didn't work. Any ideas please ? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.href` is a client side JavarScript variable, pug has no access to it.

Assuming you're using Node.js with express you can do something like this

```js
app.get("/posts/:post", (req, res) => {

    res.render("page", {
        currentURL: `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}${req.originalUrl}`
    });
});
```

then in your pug template interpolate the variable:

```
a(data-url=currentURL)= Link
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a good solution, but I have to do this for every page, I want all my pages to be shared if so desired and I have thousands of products.(each product has its link)

Comment: This should work for all pages @YoussefFannichi — you don't have to specify it per page.